# How to list files in all directories in search (find) result?

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a list of directories from the result of a search:

> $ find . -name dir
>   ./dir1
>   ./dir1/dir1.1
>   ./dir2

How can I **ls** all this directories at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these commands to do such:

1) `find . -name "dir*" -exec ls {} \;`

2) `find . -name "dir*" | xargs ls`

Comment: Both options are correct, but the second one works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the -R flag.

```
user@box:~$ ls -R
```

You can see all of the other flags [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls#Behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your command into `xargs ls`:

```
find . -name dir | xargs ls
```